# What's wrong with this layout that's causing the elevation shadow not to appear?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-elevation

I'm trying to use Android Elevation to achieve the 'shadow' look for a view. The following is the layout xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sample.app.Main2Activity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how the layout looks:
[Look ma, no shadows!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yCmX.png)

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Comment: what is android on test device?

Comment: The elevation is there in the code I posted. I've been through other materials before posting. The background is set without the alpha value as I've found that others have had problems with shadows being rendering as well. 

@mac229 Nexus, API 25. And another device was API 21.

Comment: @redflour Generally it is weird because I tested your code on API level 23 and 26 and I have shadow

Comment: It seems that it has something to do with android:cornerRadius of the background element. When the value of that is set to 0dp, or the tag is not existent at all, the shadow isn't rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll get to the answer, but some background first. I was trying to achieve the look with a custom view that used a ConstraintLayout. This view would be used in another layout. I was when I tried using a simple TextView that I realised that the shadows weren't being rendered because, thus destroying my assumption that it was something ConstraintLayout related.

**What worked?**
I know, from the documentations, that shadows and rendered using a View's background. This, I have, and indeed, it was a solid color with no alpha value (as others on SO have mentioned).
Much like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
```

It was after I added android:radius to this, and then the shadows were rendered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
</shape>
```

And if you were wondering, why not set it to 0dp? Well, the shadows disappear again when the radius values were set to 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.... maybe you need someone to do it for you then....

I used a card view instead...

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:text="hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Add these to your app gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
```

result:

[image]

and if you dont want to use a card view.....

xml -> layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:text="hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

@drawable/border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#D5E2ED"
                android:endColor="#0000"
                android:angle="90"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#D5E2ED"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- base background -->
    <item android:bottom="5dp" android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff"/>
            <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

result:

[image]

happy coding....

Comment: Great tip using a cardview, but I was looking for a way to do it with ConstraintLayout. It was only after I tried with a simple TextView that I found out that my problem isn't because of the ConstraintLayout at all.